# duplicate params get array by node.js express or vue router

Tags: node.js, express, vue.js, vue-router, query-string

I have a big problem.

On all other project I've done I used apache or Nginx and PHP.
If I have a Url like /test?param=1&param=2 the value of $_REUEST['param'] is 2.

But in Node.js (Express) I get an array [1,2]

I could use `new URLSearchParams(this.$route.fullPath)` and than the method `.get()` or `.getAll()` to get only one value. But we have a big project and many loops and usages of this.$route.query in several files.

Is it possible to filter this.$route.query on one place?
Or is express able to change the return of this params like apache/nginx?

Comment: have you checked the `req.params` object ? it should give you params in an object format

Comment: @SyedFaizan: req.params contains the path parameters, not the query parameters...

Comment: sorry i meant `req.query`, thanks for pointing it out @eol

Answer (score 1):

This is indeed a problem as express's underlying parser [works this way](https://evanhahn.com/gotchas-with-express-query-parsing-and-how-to-avoid-them/). As a workaround you could write a little helper to extract your desired value in case the query param is an array. Something like:

```
function getQueryParam(req, queryParam) {
    if (!req.query) {
        return undefined;
    }
    if (Array.isArray(req.query[queryParam])) {
        const paramArray = req.query[queryParam];
        return paramArray[paramArray.length - 1]; // always return the last provided value
    }
    return req.query[queryParam];
}
```

You can use it like this:

```
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    const paramValue = getQueryParam(req, "param");
    // do something with paramValue 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
app.use((req, res, next) => {
      if (req.query) {
        const oldQuery = JSON.stringify(req.query);
        const queryStrings = [];
        Object.keys(req.query).forEach((paramKey) => {
          if (Array.isArray(req.query[paramKey])) {
            const paramArray = req.query[paramKey];
            req.query[paramKey] = paramArray[paramArray.length - 1]; // always return the last provided value
            queryStrings.push(`${paramKey}=${req.query[paramKey]}`);
          }
        });
        const newQuery = JSON.stringify(req.query);
        if (oldQuery !== newQuery) {
          res.redirect(301, `${req.path}?${queryStrings.join('&')}`);
        }
      }
      next();
    });
```

This works by a redirect. Not the perfect thing I want, but with the same result